# Complete AJAX call before PayPal button redirects

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, paypal

I am using PayPal buttons and would like to insert a record into the database via an AJAX call (or any other method that works) before the button redirects the user to PayPal.

I have looked at similar questions/answers but can't get them to work. They either redirect to PayPal or insert a database record...but not both.

Similiar questions:
[Submit form values before paypal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041400), [PayPal Button submitting a form and triggering an Ajax call at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15416842), [AJAX request before regular form is being submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885843)

This is my form:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" name="paypalform" id="paypalform">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="XXXXXXXXXXXX">
    <button type="submit" class="radius paypal-button" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">Buy Now!
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

This is my javascript:

```
$('paypalform').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = false;
    var $form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.create_sponsorship.php',
        data: 'XXXXXX',
        dataType: 'json',
        context: $form,
        complete: function() {
            this.off('submit');
            this.submit();
        }
    });
});
```

The PHP file, ajax.create_sponsorship.php, return either TRUE (if insert was successful) or FALSE.

When using the code above the broswer successfully redirects to PayPal but does not insert record into database.

If I change the first line to this:

```
$('#paypalform').submit(function(e) {
```

Basically, adding the # - then the database record gets inserted but it doesn't redirect to PayPal.

Comment: Duplicate, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15416842/paypal-button-submitting-a-form-and-triggering-an-ajax-call-at-the-same-time .

Answer (score 0):

Update the code as below and try:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" name="paypalform" id="paypalform">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="XXXXXXXXXXXX">
<button type="submit" class="radius paypal-button prevented" name="submit" id="paypalsubmit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">Buy Now!
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

And script goes as below:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#paypalsubmit').click(function(e) {
    if($(this).hasClass('prevented')){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).removeClass('prevented');
        $.post( "ajax.create_sponsorship.php",{ data: 'XXXXXX'}, function( result ) {
            if(result){
                $('#paypalsubmit').click();
                return true;
            }
        });  
    }else{
        $('#paypalform').submit();
        $(this).addClass('prevented');
    }
    });  
    })
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. It does submit the form (redirect to PayPal) but it does not insert database record. I am watching the page traffic with Fiddler and see no call to the ajax PHP file.

Comment: updated the code: file name was wrong, now updated to ajax.create_sponsorship.php. try again..