# PHP and Paypal. When click submit, save data to database and redirect to paypal

Tags: php, paypal

I have the form below, and I wondered if there's a way, when the user click the submit button, save the data, like $shipping_price, $invoice_id to the database and redirect the user to paypal to pay.

```
    <form action="https://secure.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" name="paypal" id="paypal">
    <!-- Prepopulate the PayPal checkout page with customer details, -->
    <input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="<?php echo Firstname?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="<?php echo Lastname?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo Email?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="address1" value="<?php echo Address?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="address2" value="<?php echo Address2?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="city" value="<?php echo City?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="zip" value="<?php echo Postcode?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="day_phone_a" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="day_phone_b" value="<?php echo Mobile?>">

    <!-- We don't need to use _ext-enter anymore to prepopulate pages -->
    <!-- cmd = _xclick will automatically pre populate pages -->
    <!-- More information: https://www.x.com/docs/DOC-1332 -->
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="paypal@email.com" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="Return to Your Business Name" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP" />

    <!-- Allow the customer to enter the desired quantity -->
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Name of Item" />

    <!-- Custom value you want to send and process back in the IPN -->
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo session_id().?>" />

    <input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="<?php echo $shipping_price; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="<?php echo $invoice_id ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $total_order_price; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']?>/shop/paypal/thankyou"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']?>/shop/paypal/cancelled" />

    <!-- Where to send the PayPal IPN to. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']?>/shop/paypal/process" />
</form>
```

Comment: Check out `cURL`. This is something that can be done. Basically posting the data to your own page, entering the details in your DB, and then using curl, post the data to PayPal. Your question so far is too vague to supply a full answer for.

Comment: why are all the input fields hidden?

Comment: @gidim because i just want to show the payer the button and not the whole form.

Comment: @Twisty I will check Curl out thanks alot

Comment: You can also deal with this on the client side. submit the form with AJAX to paypal then once again to your server.

Comment: @gidim How do i do it with Ajax? I want the payer to be transfer to paypal to pay on paypal site when they click the submit button.  At the same time i want all the data to be save in the database if the same submit button is clicked.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23669948/complete-ajax-call-before-paypal-button-redirects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two way to achieve this. The first (simpler) version is to submit the form via AJAX to your server before redirecting the user to PayPal. The problem with this solution is that it if the customer does not complete the purchase for some reason you will have false data in your DB and you need to figure out a way to rollback.

In order to achieve this you can do something like this:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#submit').click(function(e) {
            if ($(this).hasClass('sent')) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).removeClass('sent');
                $.post("saveToDB.php", {
                    data: $("#paypal").serialize()
                }, function(success) {
                    if (success) {
                        $('#submit').click();
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $('#paypal').submit();
                $(this).addClass('sent');
            }
        });
    })
```

Then add the class "sent" to your submit button.

**The second approach** is to deal with entire process asynchronously and then log the result only if the process succeeded. See following example taken from [PayPal API Documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/in-context/integration/) :

HTML:

```
 <div class="row product">
      <div class="col-md-4">
          <h3>Toy Story Jessie T-Shirt</h3>
          <p>
          <form class="ajaxasync" method="POST" action="http://166.78.8.98/cgi-bin/aries.cgi?live=1&returnurl=http://166.78.8.98/cgi-bin/return.htm&cancelurl=http://166.78.8.98/cgi-bin/cancel.htm">
              <button id="t2" type="submit" class="checkout" class="paypal-button-hidden">
                  <img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/fr_FR/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif">
              </button>
          </form>
          </p>
      </div>
  </div>
```

JS:

```
window.paypalCheckoutReady = function() {
    paypal.checkout.setup("6XF3MPZBZV6HU", {
        environment: 'sandbox',
        click: function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            paypal.checkout.initXO();
            $.support.cors = true;
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://166.78.8.98/cgi-bin/aries.cgi?sandbox=1&direct=1&returnurl=http://166.78.8.98/cgi-bin/return.htm&cancelurl=http://166.78.8.98/cgi-bin/cancel.htm",
                type: "GET",
                data: '&ajax=1&onlytoken=1',   
                async: true,
                crossDomain: true,

                //Load the minibrowser with the redirection url in the success handler
                success: function (token) {
                    var url = paypal.checkout.urlPrefix +token;
                    //Loading Mini browser with redirect url, true for async AJAX calls
                    paypal.checkout.startFlow(url);
                },
                error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Error in ajax post"+responseData.statusText);
                    //Gracefully Close the minibrowser in case of AJAX errors
                    paypal.checkout.closeFlow();
                }
            });
        },
        button: ['t1', 't2']
    });
}
```

Once the transaction completes the user is returned to return.htm, this is where you log the transaction to the DB. Either by AJAX or just using PHP (and renaming return.htm to return.php)

Comment: can i use the form to transfer my customer to paypal site and then use ajax but with url to savedata.php to save the data to the database on savedata.php?

Comment: When you submit the form, I think you should first submit the data to your savedata.php via AJAX and then complete the submission of the form as expected.

Comment: @Twisty - if the call fails for some reason the data will still be logged to the DB

Comment: @gidim I don't see how that would happen. The `done()` would not execute upon failure of the AJAX.

Comment: @Twisty I meant that if the Papal POST fails you will still have it logged.

Comment: @gidim I see what you're saying. Still a chance for `done()` not to execute. Plus users are not redirected to PayPal to complete the purchase.

Comment: @Twisty - yep. I've added another approach which solves both issues.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this way, this simply submits the form programatically.

```
<script>

function sendtopapal()
{
    document.getElementById("paypal").submit(); 
}
sendtopapal();

</script>
```

Comment: Any explanation why and how your answer would work for OP?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, you could post the data to your own script first via AJAX and then allow the form to complete as expected.

```
<script>
$("#submit").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "savedata.php",
        data: $("paypal").serialize()
    });
    return true;
});
</script>
```

This should allow you to capture the data being submitted, and post the data to PayPal (along with directing the user) all at once.